# Google scholar: Search papers by all the authors with particular label

Tags: google-scholar, literature-search

Is it possible to use google scholar to search all the papers by a list of authors who has a particular label.

Example: all the papers by the authors with label:power_electronics

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: @solarmike, of course I did-but no success. Searching articles with query “author:label:Power_electronics” didn’t give any results

Comment: So, why not try the label and the last two years for example, unless you know and have a list of all the authors who published in that field...

Comment: Surprisingly, it returns some results. But articles are off topic and are not really from the targeted authors. It even includes articles whereany author doesn’t have scholar profile.

Comment: I suggest you talk to a university librarian.

Comment: I've used Google Scholar extensively, and I don't think you can carry out that type of search. The search options in Google Scholar's researcher profile service, and in the document search engine are different. The only option I can think of is that you extract the author IDs of authors that appear when you make the "label:power_electronics" search, and then use some software to extract the document lists from each profile, such as in the following example: https://twitter.com/Protohedgehog/status/999023873235537920

Comment: Thanks @alberto, however, even label:power_electronics doesn’t seems to be working for article search - the returned results (when we specify a time range) are not really relevant. it seems that “label” is relevant only for author searches - not sure though. I can obviously try “power electronics” as the search keyword for the purpose of literature search. Will give a try with your suggested approach.

Comment: label:power_electronics will only work to find authors with a Google Scholar profile, not in the document search engine. What I suggested was that you extract the IDs from each of the authors returned by the query, and then use those R functions (or some similar ones), to extract the document list of each of those authors

Comment: Got it. Please add this as the answer (for the future readers )

Answer (score 2):

If want to see papers by the authors you know, you can do it like so: `"<keyword>" + <author> + <author> ...`

[image: gif_1]

---

| Search query example | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `"<keyword>"` | double-quotes to get an exact match |
| `"<keyword>" + "<keyword>" + "..."` | filter papers by a multiple keywords |
| `"<keyword>" + "<keyword>" + "<author>"` | filter papers by a multiple keywords and author |

All of these examples seem to be working with specific date ranges and note that with every next page, results will be more irrelevant which you already wrote in the comments above.

---

Also, you can achieve it programmatically using Python and [Google Scholar Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-organic-results) from SerpApi that can help you to parse data from all available pages.

It's a paid API with a free plan that handles all the hard lifting so the end-user only needs to think about what type of data to get.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/google-scholar-search-papers-by-all-the-authors-with-parti-1):

```
import os, json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl

params = {
    # os.getenv(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # Your SerpApi API key
    "engine": "google_scholar",   
    "q": '"minecraft learning"',      # search query
    "hl": "en",                       # language
    # "as_ylo": "2017",               # from 2017
    # "as_yhi": "2021",               # to 2021
    "start": "0"                      # first page
    }

search = GoogleSearch(params)

organic_results_data = []

loop_is_true = True
while loop_is_true:
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(f"Currently extracting page №{results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('current')}..")

    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        position = result["position"]
        title = result["title"]
        publication_info_summary = result["publication_info"]["summary"]
        result_id = result["result_id"]
        link = result.get("link")
        result_type = result.get("type")
        snippet = result.get("snippet")

        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_number": results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}).get("current"),
            "position": position + 1,
            "result_type": result_type,
            "title": title,
            "link": link,
            "result_id": result_id,
            "publication_info_summary": publication_info_summary,
            "snippet": snippet,
            })

        if "next" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["serpapi_pagination"]["next"]).query)))
        else:
            loop_is_true = False

print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Part of the output:

```
[
  {
    "page_number": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "result_type": null,
    "title": "A deep hierarchical approach to lifelong learning in minecraft",
    "link": "https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/10744",
    "result_id": "a_Er9i3hDtUJ",
    "publication_info_summary": "C Tessler, S Givony, T Zahavy, D Mankowitz… - Proceedings of the …, 2017 - ojs.aaai.org",
    "snippet": "We propose a lifelong learning system that has the ability to reuse and transfer knowledge from one task to another while efficiently retaining the previously learned knowledge-base. …"
  }, ... other results
  {
    "page_number": 8,
    "position": 1,
    "result_type": "Pdf",
    "title": "A EFICIÊNCIA DA COMUNICAÇÃO RADIOFÔNICA PELA ORIENTAÇÃO DA FONOAUDIOLOGIA. 30",
    "link": "https://www.academia.edu/download/56944676/_ARTES__AMBIENTES_MIDIATICOS__EDUCACAO_E_PLATAFORMAS.pdf#page=77",
    "result_id": "kBAYMW4EwNQJ",
    "publication_info_summary": "TG da SILVA - ARTES, AMBIENTES MIDIÁTICOS, EDUCAÇÃO E … - academia.edu",
    "snippet": "Por meio dos conhecimentos e das devidas habilidades proporcionadas pela fonoaudiologia é possível identificar quais devem ser as performances vocais mais adequadas para …"
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.